# How to Play Audio On Your Website PHP / Flash?

Tags: audio

I'm just wondering how, and which audio player I should use to allow my visitors to play audio files on my website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a flash-based player cleverly called ["MP3 Player"](http://flash-mp3-player.net/). Nice looking and easy to use (and free!)

Answer (score 1):

Flash is the most widely available platform capable of playing sounds in a web page.  It is highly likely that flash is already installed in their browser.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15660.html